# opening second / third tab using external link

Tags: jquery, css

I want to open tab-2 in xyz.html by using a link in abc.html. I tried to google it out. But didn't find any simple solution.

Regards

Comment: Please post in your question the most complicated you've found

Comment: I suggest attaching a hash to the end of the link in xyz.html, specifying which tab to open. Then, on abc.html, read the location's hash when the page loads using JavaScript, to determine whether a particular tab needs to be opened. Additionally, I suggest adding a bit more effort to your questions and showing reasonable attempts at a solution, or you're liable to be downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 0):

To test open both links :

http://jsbin.com/bohad/1/edit  and  http://jsbin.com/qobaz/1/edit

now go to "bohad" demo and click the link.
Congratulations! You just communicated between two pages.

---

On page 1:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="click">Click </a>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('tab', 'openTab2');
});
```

on page 2 just set this jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('storage', function(e) {
     alert( localStorage.getItem('tab') );
});
```